# Android Sudio find which Activity/Fragment is on foreground

Tags: android, android-studio, adb

I am working on a new app and it is a bit difficult to find which Activity/Fragment corresponds to the current screen which I am seeing on the device. Is there some way to do it from the Android Studio?
For a comparison, for iOS development in Xcode I can pause app execution and see the full hierarchy of views and controllers. I am looking for a similar feature in Android Studio.

Comment: Check out [Android Studio Debugger](https://google-developer-training.github.io/android-developer-fundamentals-course-concepts-v2/unit-1-get-started/lesson-3-testing,-debugging,-and-using-support-libraries/3-1-c-the-android-studio-debugger/3-1-c-the-android-studio-debugger.html)

Comment: @rahat what to check there? I checked the layout inspector but it just shows me a hierarchy of the types of views. It won't show me which activity/fragment holds each view.